# Rails / Formtastic (Active Admin) checkboxes returns true incorrectly - using MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

So this is a difficult question to ask because I am not entirely sure how to describe it, so forgive me on the question title.

Basically, I am storing an array object inside a column in mysql. In active admin panel, I am building out the form for display.

```
form do |f|       

f.inputs "Job Details" do
  f.input :userId, label: 'User', :collection => User.all.map{ |user| [user.email, user.id] }
  f.input :employerName, label: 'Employer Name'
  f.input :employerPhone, label: 'Employer Phone'
  f.input :employerFax, label: 'Employer Fax'
  f.input :contactEmail, label: 'Job Contact Email'
  f.input :address1, label: 'Address 1'
  f.input :address2, label: 'Address 2'
  f.input :city, label: 'City'
  f.input :state, label: 'State'
  f.input :postalCode, label: 'Postal Code'
  f.input :position, label: 'Position'
  f.input :description, label: 'Description'
  f.input :compensation, label: f.object.category 
   li JobClassification.all.map{|x| [x.id, f.object.category, f.object.category.include?(x.id.to_s), {:checked=> f.object.category.include?(x.id.to_s)}] }

  if f.object.new_record?
    f.input :category, :as => :check_boxes, collection: JobClassification.all.map{|x| [x.classificationName, x.id]}
  else 
    f.input :category, :as => :check_boxes, collection: JobClassification.all.map{|x| [x.classificationName, x.id, {:checked=> f.object.category.include?(x.id.to_s)}] }
  end


end
f.actions
```

end

The line in question is the following:

```
 f.input :category, :as => :check_boxes, collection: JobClassification.all.map{|x| [x.classificationName, x.id, {:checked=> f.object.category.include?(x.id.to_s)}] }
```

The value returned from the databse `f.object.category` which is `["","16"]`

Now you would think that would run correctly and the include would check the value of the id from the map against that and if true apply the check default for that item.

However, I am getting a true result for id's 1, 6, and 16. It should only return true for 16. Here's what's odd, if I hard code in `["","16"].include?(x.id.to_s)` it works as it should and displays the correct items checked.

Here's a screenshot of the current incorrect output for guidance.
[image]

It should only return checked true for **Legal/Paralegal**

This is very bizarre and I have spent quite some time searching and testing various options. I just need another set of eyes on this that may have more specific details or point me on the right direction as to what I need to find or search for to solve this issue.

Thanks again and in advance!

Comment: If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi, what is category relationship? what type, fields?